# Multiple isolated DC-DC converters in series - ground reference question

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ground, voltage-divider, isolated

I have a question concerning multiple isolated DC-DC converters in series and ground references.

I need to measure 48 volts from the input of the first DC-DC converter via a voltage divider, and also 24 volts on the output. However my MCU is powered by an LDO (from 12 volts) which uses GND2 as reference, which is totally isolated from GND1 and GND.

Which ground reference is needed on the both voltage dividers?

[image: block diagram]

Comment: Short answer is you can't do it as is.  You'll need a way to cross the isolation barrier.  ie. measure the 48V rail, then use isolators to cross the boundary to get to GND2 reference for the MCU.

Comment: "measure the 48V rail" you mean the first voltage divider will have GND as reference ?

Comment: Yes. And then from there you can either use an isolation amp to get you to your MCU based A2D, **or** you can use an external A2D and use digital isolators to let the MCU talk to the A2D.

Comment: Ok but the external A2D and digital isolator left side needs to be powered by an isolated power supply also

Comment: Is isolation a requirement? Because if not then you can tie all grounds together and simplify your task a lot.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a power supply on the 48V side.  It however doesn't need to be an isolated power supply.  The isolation chips take care of that.

Comment: Just curious, why do we need the isolation here?

Answer (score 1):

You already have correct answer by @Aaron in the comments. This is just my two cents on the implementation.

The ADC on the source side is probably most cumbersome solution possible. You would need additional power sources for ADC chips and digital isolators. The one questionable benefit of this approach is somewhat higher measurement precision.

Isolation amp is somewhat better, but it is not easy to find isolated amplifiers for so high supply voltages on both sides, not to mention single supply rail capability.

IMHO your best option is to use simple optoisolator circuits. They are much easier to adapt to variety of the source voltages, and by changing their gain you can have two identical ranges on the outputs suitable for Arduino ADC.

The only drawback of this solution is that for better overall precision you need to ensure you are working in the linear range of the particular optoisolator chip, which may result in some non-linearity at the extreme ends of the scale.

Comment: I was trying to find an alternative solution to isolate A/D converter. My new idea (may be wrong !) is to use differential input A/D converter like ADS1115, AIN1 connected to GND and AIN0 connected to the voltage divider output, it can works or not ?

Comment: Yes, you can use voltage dividers to drop 48V and 24V to input range of some ADC chip (or breakout board). But as I mentioned above, You'd need two _separate_ ADCs (_not_ two input channels on a single chip!), two additional power sources for them and two separate isolated digital couplers.